# Write the following in the form of AX = B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse

Write the following system of equations in the form $AX = B$, and calculate the solution using the equation $X = A^{-1}B$.

$$2x - 3y = - 1$$

$$-5x +5y = 20$$

I'm not the strongest at linear algebra but I don't understand what the question is asking me over here or how to even go about solving this.

Comment: Can you convert the system of equations to a matrix equation $AX=B$, where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, $X = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right]$, and $B$ is another $1\times2$ matrix/vector?

Comment: @peterwhy the problem is i dont understand what the question is asking

Comment: I am trying to explain what the question is asking

Comment: Wait, I mean $B$ is a $2\times1$ column matrix

Comment: I am not familiar with matrices so if you could explain why I would do that, that would be great!

Answer (score 6):

Let $X = \left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right]$, then the first equation can be written, in matrix multiplication, as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}2&-3\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}-1\end{matrix}\right]$$

Similarly, the second equation can be written as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}-5&5\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}20\end{matrix}\right]$$

By combining these two equations as a system, they can be written as 
$$\begin{align*}\left[\begin{matrix}2&-3\\-5&5\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right] &= \left[\begin{matrix}-1\\20\end{matrix}\right]\\
AX &= B
\end{align*}$$

Now, if the above $A$ has an inverse, then both sides can be left-multiplied by $A^{-1}$ to get
$$\begin{align*}AX &= B\\
A^{-1}AX &= A^{-1}B\\
I_2X &= A^{-1}B\\
X &= A^{-1}B\\
\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right] &= \left[\begin{matrix}2&-3\\-5&5\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}-1\\20\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align*}$$

And then the original unknowns in the system of equation can be solved.

Comment: So that would be $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-11\\-7\end{bmatrix}$. Which means $x = -11$ and $y = -7$?

Comment: If your $x$ and $y$ fits the original equations, then that is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You have a set of linear equations.
These can be written in Matrix form: $$AX=B$$
So you can build A by using the coefficients of x and y:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & -3 \\
  -5 & 5 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

*X* is the unknown variables x and y and it is a Vector:
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

And the multiplication of Matrix A with vector X is the solution vector B:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
  -1\\
  20\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

To solve for X in linear algebra you cannot divide directly, but   accomplish this by taking the inverse of A and multiply it by B.

Comment: The 3 in the matrix A should be -3 as per the equation given.

Comment: @redgem I agree.